# How do I get assigned hours for a specific resource in a specific sprint in Azure DevOps? Is there any API available for that?

Tags: api, azure-devops, scrum, azure-boards, time-tracking

Basically, we would like to calculate the availability during each sprint as well as the entire quarter for all the developers by collecting all the assigned tasks and the corresponding original estimated hours to the developers, at Azure DevOps, from current and future sprints and use the values in the formula below.

Capacity - Original Estimated Hours = Available Hours for a sprint.

Comment: Is there a reason the "Work Details" widget on the sprint view doesn't provide the detail you want?

Comment: Work Details widget displays the assigned information for a specific sprint. We would like to compute the assigned hours for a specific resource across projects for current and future sprints.

Comment: For now there's no direct api that can calculate 'available' hours for specific spring. We have to do that one by one. Use [Capacities - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get capacities, use WorkItems-List to get Original Estimated Hours, and then get the available hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lance Li-MSFT. That is how exactly I am doing it as you mentioned in the following comment.

"For now there's no direct api that can calculate 'available' hours for specific spring. We have to do that one by one. Use Capacities - List to get capacities, use WorkItems-List to get Original Estimated Hours, and then get the available hours. – Lance Li-MSFT"

The Solution is as follows:

Use Capacities API to get the list of capacities for all resources in a sprint/iteration.
Use Work Items API to get the list of Estimated Hours for all resources in a sprint/iteration.

So available hours can easily be calculated as follows for any spring/iteration:

Capacity - Original Estimated Hours = Available Hours for a sprint for a resource.